# Browsermob HTTPS requests with Auth Headers

Tags: python, proxy, request, browsermob, browsermob-proxy

I'm trying to use Browsermob proxy to capture information about requests.
Have it working for HTTP requests and HTTPS requests that don't have an authorization header.

```
    if(product == 'Product'):
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % accessToken()
        }
    http_proxy  = "http://localhost:" + str(self.proxy.port)
    https_proxy = "https://localhost:" + str(self.proxy.port)
    ftp_proxy   = "ftp://localhost:" + str(self.proxy.port)
    proxyDict = { 
                  "http"  : http_proxy, 
                  "ftp"   : ftp_proxy,
                  "https" : https_proxy
                }
    fullurl = baseurl
    fullurl += '/'
    fullurl += baseuri
    logger.console("fullurl: '%s'" % fullurl)
    response =   requests.request(method,fullurl,proxies=proxyDict,verify=False,data=payload,headers=headers)
```

The request goes through if I remove 'proxies=proxyDict'. The request seems to time out if I go through the proxy though and I get the bellow exception:

```
Exception: Error creating SSLEngine for connection to client to impersonate upstream host: null
    at net.lightbody.bmp.mitm.manager.ImpersonatingMitmManager.clientSslEngineFor(ImpersonatingMitmManager.java:227) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyToServerConnection$3.execute(ProxyToServerConnection.java:739) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ConnectionFlow.doProcessCurrentStep(ConnectionFlow.java:140) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ConnectionFlow.processCurrentStep(ConnectionFlow.java:128) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ConnectionFlow.advance(ConnectionFlow.java:90) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ConnectionFlowStep.onSuccess(ConnectionFlowStep.java:83) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ConnectionFlow$2.operationComplete(ConnectionFlow.java:149) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:683) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyLateListener(DefaultPromise.java:624) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:139) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:93) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:28) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ConnectionFlow.doProcessCurrentStep(ConnectionFlow.java:140) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ConnectionFlow.access$000(ConnectionFlow.java:14) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ConnectionFlow$1.run(ConnectionFlow.java:124) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.run(PromiseTask.java:73) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:358) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:374) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:212) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4790) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at net.lightbody.bmp.mitm.manager.ImpersonatingMitmManager.getHostnameImpersonatingSslContext(ImpersonatingMitmManager.java:242) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    at net.lightbody.bmp.mitm.manager.ImpersonatingMitmManager.clientSslEngineFor(ImpersonatingMitmManager.java:223) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0.jar:?]
    ... 20 more
```

Does browsermob handle authorization like this or am I just doing it wrong? Is there another proxy solution that might work better for this? I'm looking to use the har results.

Answer (score 0):

From the error log, I'm guessing it's one of two problems:

1. a bug in browsermob. Try upgrading to a newer version
2. a mismatch between the domain browsermob thinks it's running against, and the domain you're connecting to. try switching to your explicit ip as the hostname - ie: "127.0.0.1" instead of  "localhost"

This doesn't appear to be related to authorization headers.